# Sending calendar invitations using Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm experimenting with Microsoft Graph to create calendar events in Microsoft 365.  I have noticed that when I specify attendees, only attendees who have non-M365 domains actually receive invitations. Attendees who have a "onmicrosoft.com" domain, or some custom domain tied to M365, receive nothing.  What's the reason for that?

Also, I would like to know if there is a way to just not send any invitations at all. In Exchange Web Services, sending invitations is optional when creating a meeting.

Comment: `if there is a way to just not send any invitations at all` may be you can try to set `isReminderOn`  as false. See [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that does not work.  Based on this thread (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/ability-to-update-or-create-an-event-without-sending-a/idc-p/3286874#M887) there does not seem to be a way right now to turn off notifications/invitations.

Comment: Update to my original post - it turns out that the invitations were in fact delivered, but for some reason, M365 considered them to be junk mail and were filtered from the inbox.  Seems a strange thing for M365 to do, but I guess we can live with it.